# ¿Cómo crear un trigger que elimine la última fila de una tabla al insertar?

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo el siguiente script:

Lo que quiero es eliminar el último registro de mi tabla. Al insertar a la tabla reservas. Ya que al registrarse se registra dos veces seguida a mi tabla.

```
create trigger delete_last_row
    on
    dbo.reservas
    after insert
    as
    begin

    declare @numero int
    declare @iam int

    set @iam=(select  IAM_CodInterno from inserted)
    set @numero=(select max(numero) from Reservas where IAM_CodInterno=@iam)

    delete from Reservas
    where IAM_CodInterno=@iam and NUMERO=@numero

    end
```

Comment: Por qué se inserta 2 veces? Así debe ser? Qué error tienes con el trigger?

Comment: ¿Y si corriges tu código para que se inserte una sola vez en vez de borrar una de las filas?

Answer (score 0):

Hola Kevin Quevedo Bonifacio:

Siempre pensando que como te ha dicho @Luis Cazares, será mucho mejor invertir tiempo en subsanar el código que utilizar un trigger para corregirlo.

Una posible solución, puede ser tal que:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.reservas (IAM_CodInterno int, Numero int)
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.delete_last_row on
dbo.Reservas
after insert
as
begin

;with cte as (
    Select Iam_CodInterno, Numero,
    Row_number() over(partition by Iam_codInterno order by Numero desc)as row
        from inserted
    )
    delete from r 
    from reservas as r
    inner join cte as c on r.IAM_CodInterno = c.IAM_CodInterno and r.Numero =  c.Numero
    where c.row = 1 

end
go
```

Esto es válido, si las insercciones se producen en la misma transacción.

```
insert into dbo.reservas (IAM_CodInterno, numero)
values
(1,1),
(1,2),
(2,1),
(2,2);
go
select * from dbo.reservas
go
```

Salida query

[image: Salida query]

Caso de que esas inserciones no se produczcan en la misma transacción, entonces tienes que exponer mucho mejor el diseño de tú tabla, y el escenario, como funciona para poder darte una solución.